# Website to connect to a client desktop application

Tags: php, javascript, vb.net, tcp, web

I have an application written in **VB.net** that runs on a clients pc.
I also have a website written in mostly javascript, http and php.
**The thing I want to do is to connect the website to the application**, so that when i.e. a certain button is pressed, it connects to the client application and raises an event.

I have tried approaches like **TCP socket communication** by having a TCP Socket Server running in the background of the client application. I can connect to the server by having a client connection from another vb.net application, but whenever I try to connect through PHP it fails. (I have only tried PHP since server-side scripting seems to make more sense in this case)

Another approach I have tried is to have an **HTTP server** running in the background of my desktop application and then have a PHP script connect to it, that fails as well.

One thing that I've been thinking about as a last resort is to simply have a textfile on the webserver and a PHP script writing to it after given parameters and then have the client application to read the file every few seconds. But this wouldn't be very efficient with larger amounts of data, would it?

What is the proper way of doing this? 
If you have any questions about the code I've been using, feel free to ask.

If you don't get my blurry explanation, try this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3RO4.png

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: is there a reason you want your website to connect to desktop app rather than using an api?

Comment: What do you mean? Please elaborate :)

Comment: It seems like a more logical path to take to me that's all.

Answer (score 0):

To have your data more organized i would suggest you to store your data on a database server for example mysql (which is free).

Comment: I have thought about that, but haven't succeded with  it. If you could give me a sample code, maybe I could make it work?
Thank you.

Comment: Check this for the VB part: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493133/Connecting-to-mysql-databases-using-VB-NET

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I haven't worked a lot with MySQL and that's mostly why I have been trying to escape that route. I have tried this once before, but I guess I'll try once more. Thank you!